# How can I thaw an inaccessible pipe?

Tags: plumbing

The previous owners of my home covered the old basement stairs to add a small mudroom and a half bath. They must have added the plumbing before placing the floors because, from what I can gather, it is tight against the foundation of the home and is unable to be accessed because it is behind the old cement staircase.

The previous owners covered the old staircase with flooring and built on a 1/2 bath that extends past where the stairs are. When they did, they must have put plumbing under the floor of the 1/2 bath foundation that is behind the old staircase against the foundation. There is a very small crawl space to reach the pipe that leads to the sink but the pipe is frozen behind that beam and staircase.

I shimmied in as far as I can in an attempt to reach the little bit of pipe extending to my sink to at least try to apply some heat in the hope that the heat would hopefully reach the area that I can't. I'm afraid of applying to something that I can't see.  How can I thaw it?

Comment: Put a hair dryer, or small electric heater in that space and warm the entire crawl space it may not take long once the area warms up.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get through the floor in a hidden place, such as under an appliance or cabinet, you may need to bring someone in with high-current welder. That and an understanding of the risks will make quick work of the plug.

[Random YouTube search result](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_mFAmHgC-g) for vague reference